# Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2) OID in server certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate

For a project I'm working on I have to generate web server certificate.
As I understand it, server certificates should contain the Server Authentication OID (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1). But as I see all server certificates issued by well known issuers like Verisign contain also Client Authentication OID (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2).

I tried to use certificate with only server authentication OID - seems it works fine.

#### Questions

- Why is the client authentication OID needed for server certificates?
- Is it needed for some legacy support or there is another reason for it?

Answer (score 14):

The difference between the two is exactly how they're described.

For using a certificate as a server (on the *receiving* end of the connection), it must have the Server extended key usage.

In a 2-way SSL connection, where the client (on the *initiating* end of the connection) presents a certificate back to the server, it must have the Client extended key usage.

If you're never using the certificate as a client cert, you won't need the Client Authentication OID.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is also useful to point out that one of the main distinctions between Client and Server certificates is that:

1. Server Certificates are used for encryption and decryption of data;
2. Client Certificates represent a user identity. That is, to prove the client's identity to a remote server.

Comment: That is not entirely accurate. A server certificate also proves the server's identity. When the server certificate is signed by a trusted CA, then you have reasonable assurance that you're actually talking to the real server and not some man-in-the-middle.

Comment: @geofflee Yes, you are correct. I guess I was trying to point out something that was totally missed by the first answer. Client Certificates very much represent an end-user's identity. I think that is a little more meaningful than it has the Client extended key usage. As the OP has awarded neither answer, I believe they did not  find either too helpful. We can only try :)

Comment: Server Certificates are not used for encrypting the data. It's only for identification. A symmetric session key is negotiated during the handshake and that is what is used for encryption.

Comment: @OrangeDog thanks, yes I have learnt that since. Where does the key actually live? Is it a private key stored in the server cert store when the pfx is installed?

Comment: @onefootswilln not at all (imagine the size of the certicate store of your child that discover the web ;)), the session private key is derived from both certificates (and remains in memory). It is renewed periodically. See 2.2 Shared Secret Negotiation in https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-52r1.pdf