# Cipher selection for sslStream in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, sslstream

I am trying to create a TLS1.1/TLS1.2 server using .Net's sslStream class. It appears that by default the only cipher suites that this stream accepts are:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

I'd like to enable non-ECDHE versions of these (i.e. TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256). I googled around a bit and people talk about changing cipher suites by modifying the default SChannel settings -- either through the "SSL Cipher Suite Order" or using CNG functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930(v=vs.85).aspx

However, I tried this and I can't get anything to work. Using the above link's C++ code to list the enabled cipher suites with `BCryptEnumContextFunctions()` shows that the cipher suites I want are enabled by default. I even added TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 as a top priority suite, and sslStream still refuses a TLS connection from a client that only supports that cipher (Exception: "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm") Any idea what is going on here?

(By the way, if my client supports one of the ECDHE cipher suites, everything works great)

How are other folks implementing TLS in .Net 4.5? Should I be looking at opensource solutions? What about a wrapper for SChannel to use the CNG api more directly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft's technical support and after using their proprietary tracing ability, it turned out that the certificate I had installed on my server did not have it's private key marked as an "exchange key". Apparently the private key counterpart of every public key in the certificate store has certain uses for which it it is allowed. In my case, the private key was only allowed to be used for signatures and was not allowed to be used for encrypting a symmetric key during the SSL/TLS handshake. This meant that my server could only support ECDHE cipher suites.

It also turns out that you can't check the enabled uses of a private key in the Certificate MMC snap-in. Making matters worse, using the sslStream class, there is also no way of determining any information for a handshake failure beyond the generic exception "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm".

The final thing to mention is how I managed to install a server certificate with a restricted private key in the first place. It turns out that I generated it that way. I was using the CertEnroll COM interface to programmatically generate a certificate signing request which I exported, had a certificate authority sign, and installed the certificate authority's response.  The C# code that I used to generate the certificate signing request accidentally created a private key that was only enabled for signature use.

From my experience, the CertEnroll interface is difficult to use and it's hard to find working examples online. So for others' reference I am including my C# code that generates a base64 encoded certificate signing request functional for SSL/TLS handshakes. In my case, the line `objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE;` was missing.

```
using CERTENROLLLib;
using CERTCLILib;

public string GenerateRequest(string Subject, StoreLocation Location)
{
    //code originally came from: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c.aspx
    //modified version of it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755634/issue-generating-a-csr-in-windows-vista-cx509certificaterequestpkcs10
    //here is the standard for certificates: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3280.txt


    //the PKCS#10 certificate request (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377505.aspx)
    CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 objPkcs10 = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();

    //assymetric private key that can be used for encryption (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378921.aspx)
    CX509PrivateKey objPrivateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();

    //access to the general information about a cryptographic provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375967.aspx)
    CCspInformation objCSP = new CCspInformation();

    //collection on cryptographic providers available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375967(v=vs.85).aspx
    CCspInformations objCSPs = new CCspInformations();

    CX500DistinguishedName objDN = new CX500DistinguishedName();

    //top level object that enables installing a certificate response http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377809.aspx
    CX509Enrollment objEnroll = new CX509Enrollment();
    CObjectIds objObjectIds = new CObjectIds();
    CObjectId objObjectId = new CObjectId();
    CObjectId objObjectId2 = new CObjectId();
    CX509ExtensionKeyUsage objExtensionKeyUsage = new CX509ExtensionKeyUsage();
    CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();

    string csr_pem = null;

    //  Initialize the csp object using the desired Cryptograhic Service Provider (CSP)
    objCSPs.AddAvailableCsps();

    //Provide key container name, key length and key spec to the private key object
    objPrivateKey.ProviderName = providerName;
    objPrivateKey.Length = KeyLength;
    objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE; //Must flag as XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE to use this certificate for exchanging symmetric keys (needed for most SSL cipher suites)
    objPrivateKey.KeyUsage = X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_ALL_USAGES;                
    if (Location == StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
        objPrivateKey.MachineContext = true;
    else
        objPrivateKey.MachineContext = false; //must set this to true if installing to the local machine certificate store

    objPrivateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG;    //must set this if we want to be able to export it later. 
    objPrivateKey.CspInformations = objCSPs;

    //  Create the actual key pair
    objPrivateKey.Create();

    //  Initialize the PKCS#10 certificate request object based on the private key.
    //  Using the context, indicate that this is a user certificate request and don't
    //  provide a template name
    if (Location == StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
        objPkcs10.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine, objPrivateKey, "");
    else
        objPkcs10.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, objPrivateKey, "");

    //Set hash to sha256
    CObjectId hashobj = new CObjectId();
    hashobj.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID, ObjectIdPublicKeyFlags.XCN_CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ANY, AlgorithmFlags.AlgorithmFlagsNone, "SHA256");
    objPkcs10.HashAlgorithm = hashobj;

    // Key Usage Extension -- we only need digital signature and key encipherment for TLS:
    //  NOTE: in openSSL, I didn't used to request any specific extensions. Instead, I let the CA add them
    objExtensionKeyUsage.InitializeEncode(
        CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE |
        CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE
    );
    objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objExtensionKeyUsage);

    // Enhanced Key Usage Extension
    objObjectId.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"); // OID for Server Authentication usage (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477279/client-authentication-1-3-6-1-5-5-7-3-2-oid-in-server-certificates)
    objObjectId2.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"); // OID for Client Authentication usage (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477279/client-authentication-1-3-6-1-5-5-7-3-2-oid-in-server-certificates)
    objObjectIds.Add(objObjectId);
    objObjectIds.Add(objObjectId2);
    objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage.InitializeEncode(objObjectIds);
    objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)objX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage);

    //  Encode the name in using the Distinguished Name object
    // see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379394(v=vs.85).aspx     
    objDN.Encode(
        Subject,
        X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_SEMICOLON_FLAG
    ); 

    // Assign the subject name by using the Distinguished Name object initialized above
    objPkcs10.Subject = objDN;

    //suppress extra attributes:
    objPkcs10.SuppressDefaults = true;

    // Create enrollment request
    objEnroll.InitializeFromRequest(objPkcs10);
    csr_pem = objEnroll.CreateRequest(
        EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64
    );
    csr_pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\r\n" + csr_pem + "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----";

    return csr_pem;
}
```

Comment: You said it is not listed in MMC, can't you check for "data encipherment" is under the [`key usage`](http://support.citrix.com/article/html/images/1CTX136141-3.gif)?

Comment: You can check that, but that value doesn't actually matter to SChannel if the private key was not initially created with `objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE;` I had a signed certificate with the Key Usage set to 'key encipherment' and the handshake still did not work.