# Self signed certificate: Private key questions

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate2, certenroll

To implement TLS encryption via SslStream i am using a self signed certificate.
I am experiencing strange "no common algorithm" errors for clients connecting from an older Win2003 machine.

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825663/cipher-selection-for-sslstream-in-net-4-5/23001568#23001568) i discovered the following:

Those errors disappear if i change my certificate generation procedure (more specifically: the private key generation part):

Old:

```
     var privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
     privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
     privateKey.MachineContext = true;
     privateKey.Length = 2048;
     privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE
     privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;
     privateKey.Create();
```

New:

```
     var privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
     privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
     privateKey.MachineContext = true;
     privateKey.Length = 1024;
     privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE; 
     privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;
     privateKey.Create();
```

My questions (may sound stupid, sorry for that; i'm fairly new to TLS & co):

- Which algorithms are relaying on a private key with this keySpec value? Can I see somewhere which algo has been taken by SslStream?
- Why do I have to reduce the key length to 1024? Any value above will cause an exception to occur when calling Create().
- Am I taking security risks with these changes?
- Any suggestions refering to fixing the Win2K03 machine are also welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0` is the most limited of the cryptographic providers. For AT_EXCHANGE it is limited to 1024-bit RSA, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931357(v=vs.85).aspx.

Your TLS error probably comes from the SChannel library wanting to use the RSA key in AT_EXCHANGE mode even on ciphersuites where RSA signature is used, but not RSA encryption, since your two files differ in both keyspec and value.

`Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider` is the newest (added in XP SP3) CSP, if you change to that you should be able to make RSA AT_EXCHANGE keys up to length 16384 (though it'll take hours to do so, so you might want to stick to your 2048).